# Stop blender from creating redundant animations for each new object

Tags: animation, objects

I'm creating a player character asset in Blender for use in Unity. I'm separating the armor and weapons into separate objects and attaching them all to the same rig so they animate in sync.

The problem is that several animations are created for these objects which is annoying as they are all empty animations that add nothing to the asset. How do I delete these animations or, better yet, stop Blender from doing it in the first place?

Comment: I deleted the redundant animations by right clicking in the outliner and removing animation data from the individual objects. This worked and Unity is no longer freezing whenever I try and open the asset (due to the eighty or so animations it was trying to load). It would still be great to know how to stop this from happening at all.

Comment: Although this is a really old question, I could not yet find an answer. Can meanwhile somebody tell me how I could prevent freshly created objekts from getting an animation?